# No module named pyopencl (Py2exe)

Tags: python, py2exe, pyopencl

I am having some trouble with the PyOpenCL module when trying to make a .exe from Py2Exe.
Py2Exe makes the .exe as it should do (No "ImportError: No module named pyopencl" here), but when I am running the .exe it says no module named pyopencl.

I am trying to make a .exe of the Phoenix Miner.

My setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os, pyopencl

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1,
                          "includes":["pyopencl","twisted",
                                      "zope","QueueReader",
                                      "numpy"]}},
    console=[{'script' : 'phoenix.py'}],
    data_files=["C:\\Users\\Nicklas\\Desktop\\Phoenix-Miner\\kernels\\poclbm\\kernel.cl"],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

I found someone who had the same problem as me http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/848048-py2exe-module-error but with no solution.

**UPDATE:
I found what was causing this error. In pyopencl `__init__` there is a function called _find_pyopencl_include_path, it is quite self explanatory what it does. To make a long story short: the imp module fails to find the pyopencl module. To fix this I commented out that line and set pathname to the path to pyopencls include directory. Probably not a good fix. But it was an easy fix.**

Comment: It's actually OK to answer your own questions. Put `py2exe` in the title, and it would make a good self-answered question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what was causing this error. In pyopencl `__init__` there is a function called `_find_pyopencl_include_path`, it is quite self explanatory what it does. To make a long story short: the `imp` module fails to find the `pyopencl` module. To fix this I commented out that line and set pathname to the path to pyopencls include directory. Probably not a good fix. But it was an easy fix.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it saved me some time today when I ran into the same problem doing a new GUIMiner release.

Comment: Know what's funny? look at the comment just below that line:
# Who knew Python installation is so uniform and predictable?

Answer (score 0):

There is also easiest way to make python script executable by using `auto-py-to-exe` module, it can be installed using `pip install auto-py-to-exe` and after installing write `auto-py-to-exe` in python command line terminal a window will appear, choose the script location and choose OneFile instead of OneDirectory, for reference here I am pasting the `auto-py-to-exe` window screenshot 
[image]
After converting 'open output folder' option will appear where you'll get your .exe file of python script. And this .exe file run on any system without using python.